# Switching to Android, how do I handle music?

Tags: music, music-player, samsung-galaxy-note

My wife and I are planning on switching from apple phones to the Note III when it comes out later in the month. I was preparing to switch my music collection from itunes based to google play by uploading and organizing everything to the google play web app. However, I ran into a couple of issues.

- I have a computer that plays background music during the day, regardless of if we are home or not. Up to now I have been playing it through itunes, however since I have been pulling the google play web app during day, I have noticed that if I play music from work, that I come home and the music has stopped playing because you can only stream music from one device at one. I would like to have this music playing at all times.
- I assume, since my wife and I share the same music collection that we will both sign in to google play using the same google ID. However, if only one device can stream at a time, what happens when I am listening at work and she is wanting to listen at work. Will it kill one of the streams?

Has anyone else run into this? Is there another way to manager music on the Android platform?

Comment: You could just always leave your iTunes setup as-is. Google Play Music can sync directly from that.

Comment: You don't have to use Google Play Music to play music on Android. There are many other options: you could store music on each device and keep them in sync with a general-purpose file sync app, or set up your own streaming music server on your "background music" computer.